# plotly dash: two dropdowns and two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a problem with dropdowns and can't handle two DataFrames...here is my code

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

raw_cut = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Test\Test.xlsx",)
```

My Df looks like:

| GESCHLECHT_VP1 | B_oder_R |
| --- | --- |
| M | B |
| W | B |
| W | R |
| M | R |
| M | R |

Here, I have a column called "GESCHLECHT_VP1" with the gender M and W and I have a column called "B_oder_R", which tell me if a person have the option "B" or "R".

What I want to do is to bar plot interactive the number and percentage of gender and of the options B and R independently - here: 3/5 M, 2/5 W and 2/5 B, 3/5 R. I actually do NOT want to know "B or R" per Gender...for example for gender M there is one time B and two times R are not interesting.

I want that the user can first 1) choose between "Geschlecht" and "B- und R-Abschluss".
After that, I want that the user can 2) see the number or percentage of one of these two.

I made it, that one can choose between number and percentage for Geschlecht, but I don't know how to make the switch between the two graphs/dataframes "Geschlecht" and "B- und R-Abschluss".

```
# gender m or w
mf = (
    raw_cut["GESCHLECHT_VP1"]
    .value_counts()
    .rename_axis("Geschlecht")
    .reset_index(name="Anzahl")
)
mf["Prozent"] = mf["Geschlecht"].map(
    raw_cut["GESCHLECHT_VP1"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1)
)

# B and R 
br = (
    raw_cut["B_oder_R"]
    .value_counts()
    .rename_axis("BR")
    .reset_index(name="Anzahl")
)
br["Prozent"] = br["BR"].map(
    raw_cut["B_oder_R"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1)
)
```

Now I make the Dash App

```
app = Dash(__name__)

# here I define a new DataFrame to switch between the two options of 1)
wasliste = pd.DataFrame()
wasliste["was"] = ["Geschlecht", "B- und R-Abschluss"]

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H1("Übersicht: Risp und Inzidenzn - Datengrundlage"),
                html.P("Einheit"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="was",
                    options=[
                        {"label": "Geschlecht", "value": "was"},
                        {"label": "B- und R-Abschluss", "value": "was"},
                    ],
                    value="Geschlecht",
                ),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="einheitdropdown",
                    options=[
                        {
                            "label": "Anzahl",
                            "value": "Anzahl",
                        },
                        {"label": "Prozent", "value": "Prozent"},
                    ],
                    value="Prozent",
                ),
                dcc.Graph(id="Ohne Differenzierung"),
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(),  # hier Layout für rechts einfügen (wenn das klappt)
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("Ohne Differenzierung", "figure"),
    [Input("einheitdropdown", "value"), Input("was", "value")],
)
def updaten(einheitdropdown, what):
    if what == "Geschlecht":

        if einheitdropdown == "Prozent":
            figure1 = px.bar(
                mf,
                x="Geschlecht",
                y="Prozent",
                color="Geschlecht",
                barmode="group",
            )
        if einheitdropdown == "Anzahl":
            figure1 = px.bar(
                mf,
                x="Geschlecht",
                y="Anzahl",
                color="Geschlecht",
                barmode="group",
            )
    return figure1

    if what == "B- und R-Abschluss":

        if einheitdropdown == "Prozent":
            figure2 = px.bar(
                br,
                x="BR",
                y="Prozent",
                color="BR",
                barmode="group",
            )
        if einheitdropdown == "Anzahl":
            figure2 = px.bar(
                br,
                x="BR",
                y="Anzahl",
                color="BR",
                barmode="group",
            )
    return figure2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=3040)
```

This is not working. Can someone help?

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide a sample of `raw_cut` so we can reproduce your dash app and help you figure out why it's not working? you can copy and paste the output from `raw_cut.head(10).to_dict()` into your question – thanks!

Comment: did not work, but I somehow made it :) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H1("Übersicht: Risp und Inzidenzen - Datengrundlage"),
                html.P("Kriterium"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="kriteriumsdropdown",
                    options=[
                        {"label": i, "value": i}
                        for i in zs.Kriterium.drop_duplicates()
                    ],
                    value="Geschlecht",
                ),
                html.P("Einheit"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="einheitdropdown",
                    options=[
                        {
                            "label": "Anzahl",
                            "value": "Anzahl",
                        },
                        {"label": "Prozent", "value": "Prozent"},
                    ],
                    value="Prozent",
                ),
                dcc.Graph(id="Ohne Differenzierung"),
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(
            [html.H2("Platzhalter")]
        ), 
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("Ohne Differenzierung", "figure"),
    [Input("einheitdropdown", "value"), Input("kriteriumsdropdown", "value")],
)
def updaten(einheitdropdown, kriteriumsdropdown):
    if kriteriumsdropdown == "Geschlecht":
        if einheitdropdown == "Prozent":
            figure1 = px.bar(
                mf,
                x="Konkret",
                y="Prozent",
                color="Konkret",
                barmode="group",
                labels={"Konkret": "Geschlecht"},
                # color_discrete_map= {"W": "pink", "M": "gray"}
                # wenn y stetig und nicht diskret ist: color_continuos_scale = px.colors.diverging.Picnic, range_color = [1,1000]
            )
        if einheitdropdown == "Anzahl":
            figure1 = px.bar(
                mf,
                x="Konkret",
                y="Anzahl",
                color="Konkret",
                barmode="group",
                labels={"Konkret": "Geschlecht"},
            )
        return figure1

    elif kriteriumsdropdown == "BR":
        if einheitdropdown == "Prozent":
            figure2 = px.bar(
                br,
                x="Konkret",
                y="Prozent",
                color="Konkret",
                barmode="group",
                labels={"Konkret": "B oder R"},
            )
        if einheitdropdown == "Anzahl":
            figure2 = px.bar(
                br,
                x="Konkret",
                y="Anzahl",
                color="Konkret",
                barmode="group",
                labels={"Konkret": "B oder R"},
            )
        return figure2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=3040)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).